# OpenFileDialog - InitialDirectory open a remote directory

Tags: c#

I have been trying to use the InitialDirectory on remote server without success.
What I am trying to do is that: (comboBox1 has name of servers)

```
OpenFileDialog ofLogFile = new OpenFileDialog();
ofLogFile.Title = "Log for server: " + comboBox1.text;
OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "\\\\" + comboBox1.text + "\\c$";
ofLogFile.RestoreDirectory = true;
```

and then there is an if check..

But it doesnt work. All i get is the local machine directoies. 
The thing is, when i put into InitialDirectory-

```
    OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"\\server_name\c$";
```

It works just fine.
Another thing that i tried to put is:

```
OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "\\\\" + ((System.Data.DataRowView)
(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem)).ToString + "\\c$";
```

It also doesnt work.

I am starting the program with the appropriate permissions so it shouldn't be an issue.
any suggestions?

Comment: Try a non $ (hidden) directory.

Comment: it won't work because it's a remote machine.

Comment: Why use the @ symbol for one case and not the other? What output do you get if you put this in a variable: "\\\\" + comboBox1.text + "\\c$"? Do a Debug.PrintLline() and see if the variable makes sense that way.

Comment: But you state @"\\server_name\c$" works so how can conclude it does not work because it is remote?

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't it be:

```
ofLogFile.InitialDirectory = "\\\\" + comboBox1.text + "\\c$";
```

?

Comment: yes, I completely missed that. It was uncompilable for other reasons, so I guess I assumed that they simply typed it wrong here and not in code.

Comment: There might be more comboboxes i'm not aware of but the one in System.Windows.Forms has .Text!

Comment: `ComboBox.Text` is inherited from `Control`. It does nothing useful on a ComboBox.

Comment: It works fine for me! I can assign a value to .Text and it will be displayed in the ComboBox. I can also read the text shown in the ComboBox using .Text

Comment: Then I guess Text is a synonym for SelectedText. I didn't know that, nor would I ever rely on that. SelectedText is more understandable.

Comment: @Tergiver Why guess when documentation is readily avaialble.  Gets or sets the text associated with this control. (Overrides Control.Text.)   +1 banging

Comment: Wait a second.. I always forget that ComboBox has a mode other than DropDownList (which is the only way I ever use them). The Text member is the value of the Edit control in a non-DropDownList ComboBox. So you're correct--If they are not using DropDownList.

Comment: @Tergiver: not true again! .Text works even with DropDownList. However, you can only set .Text to something that is already an item!

Comment: @Tergiver Wrong again. I also verified .Text works with a DropDownList.   Come on before you criticize (a 4th time) test.

Comment: First of all I freely admit that I am wrong about the Text method. I learned something new, thank you. Second, I object to the assertion that I criticized anyone. Refuting a fact (even incorrectly) is not a criticism. Anyhow, we're back to exactly what my answer says: The combo box does not contain the correct text.

Comment: @Tergiver .Text is property not a method. "Nor would I ever rely on that" is not  exactly a compliment.  You did have the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If

```
ofLogFile.InitialDirectory = @"\\server_name\c$";
```

Works, but

```
ofLogFile.InitialDirectory = @"\\" + comboBox1.Text + @"\c$";
```

Does not work, the answer seems obvious:

`comboBox1.Text` does not contain the correct string.

Make sure the combo box text does not contain easily missed characters like leading or trailing spaces.